# Neural network in R to predict stock return

Tags: r, neural-network

I am using neuralnet package and using neuralnet function to train my data and compute to predict.

```
x <- neuralnet( X15  ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X8, norm_ind[1:15000,],2,act.fct="tanh",linear.output=TRUE)
pr <- compute(x,testdata)
```

The problem I am facing is `pr$net.result` value is almost constant for all data points.

I am predicting return of stock and providing stock real return one day ahead as target function i.e. `X15` in formula. Output I am getting is almost constant as you can see below. 
Could anyone tell me what needs to be done?

```
1084 0.00002217204168
1085 0.00002217204168
1086 0.00002217204168
1087 0.00002217204168
1088 0.00002217204168
1089 0.00002217204168
1090 0.00002217204168
1091 0.00002217204168
1092 0.00002217204168
1093 0.00002217204168
1094 0.00002217204168
1095 0.00002217204168
1096 0.00002217204168
1097 0.00002217204168
1098 0.00002217204168
1099 0.00002217204168
1100 0.00002217204168
```

Comment: possibly should be migrated to stats.SE?

Comment: I'm not really that familiar with R, but i Googled the package you refer to and according to the manual I found there is supposed to be a structure containing data about how training went in the output. Have you checked that? What does it say? Did it converge? How many iterations etc.. Without more detail it is hard to tell whats wrong.. Also, when it comes to number of hidden neurons there is no rules, only heuristics, try a sufficiently large number (20?) for starters.

Answer (score 3):

Before teaching a neural network via `neuralnet`, it is strongly advised to scale your data:

```R
learn <- scale(learn)
# be honest and use the mean and scaling inferred from the training set -
# the test set could in principle contain only one element causing an incorrect scaling
test <- scale(test, center = attributes(learn)$`scaled:center`, scale = attributes(learn)$`scaled:scale`)
model <- neuralnet(formula, learn, ...)
compute(model, test)$net.result
```

Neural networks are sensitive to shifting and scaling of the data. Additionally, the initial weights are chosen randomly from a distribution alike to a standard normal one.

See, for example, chapter 3.2, "Preprocessing" (and much more) in an excellent paper by Yoshua Bengio [1].

**Modern update:** Modern networks usually approach this sensitivity by using normalization layers, possibly with trained parameters. The most well-known and popular is Batch Normalization [2].

[1] http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5533

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_normalization

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the problem, but only having 2 hidden nodes may be responsible for the issue.

Comment: I tried even with 3-4 number of neurons but still getting almost same result. Could you tell me how many hidden layers should be appropriate. I am feeding 1500 days of 9 dimensional data. 9 dimension repersent my 9 input neuron, Hidden layer contain 2  or 3 or 4 neurons and 1 output. 1. Could you guide me how many number of neuron hidden layer should have? 2. Which activation function I should use for stock return. I tried using tanh or tanh in hidden layer and liner output layer combination

Comment: There's a somewhat dated paper by N. Wanas, G. Auda, M.S. Kamel and F. Karray entitled "On the Optimal Number of Hidden Nodes in a Neural Network" that may be of some help. The number of hidden layers depends on the complexity of the data, but I believe most applications only require one hidden layer. There's another good paper from S.L. Ozesmi, C.O. Tan and U. Ozesmi in Ecological Modeling called "Methodological issues in building, training and testing artificial neural networks in ecological applications." Why be worried about activation function and not error function?

Comment: I could sort out the problem. But I has another issue that stock price are not predicted precisely.                                 2833.00 2833.69 2835.95
87  2833.25 2834.05 2837.50
88  2834.50 2835.59 2839.50
89  2835.00 2835.90 2840.80
90  2834.20 2833.88 2841.00
91  2835.00 2835.41 2841.55
92  2835.00 2835.80 2841.50
93  2835.85 2836.69 2843.00
94  2834.90 2834.32 2842.00
95  2835.25 2835.37 2842.00
96  2835.95 2836.57 2842.00

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. It could be that your predictor variables aren't really associated with stock price. It could be something with underfitting or overfitting the network or something to do with the structure of the neural net (activation/error function, hidden layers, hidden nodes). How long does the network take before convergence? Turn 'lifesign' on full and get some realtime output so you can feel out what's going on. Set the threshold value lower than default. Basically, just trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `learningrate` argument in your `neuralnet` function to something like `learningrate=0.01`

The default is NULL and I've found this to cause a similar problem when carrying out similar tests using nnet()

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem, and I think that it may be due to the problem of local minima in traditional neural networks.  You may have to go beyond the neuralnet package to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that you have too many input variables for the amount of training data available.

Here is good information concerning this topic

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65292/r-neuralnet-compute-give-a-constant-answer